RTE hyperlink for media showing different hostname
We are encountering some unusual issues with links created using the Sitecore Rich Text Editor.
Here's the scenario:
1. Microsite Links (Page Item):
We have a microsite at https://micro.site.com/. When we generate a hyperlink for the text by selecting the page item within the context site, it generates the hyperlink in the front end with the same hostname, something like https://micro.site.com/about-us/bla bla bla.
2. Media Links (Media Item):
When we create a hyperlink for the text by selecting the media item, then it generates the hyperlink on the front end with the public website hostname, something like https://public.site.com/-/media/bla-bla-bla.jpg.
We are unsure why there is a specific difference in media item links. Any insights into why this is happening?
Sitecore version: 10.3 XP
Edit-1: We tried with MediaServerUrl setting but it is applying across the public site and microsite but we want site specific URLs only in the RTE.

Which Sitecore version? Do you have that public.site.com hostname in any config?

Yes, we have different site definition configs for public sites and microsites, and Sitecore version is 10.3

Possible Reasons for the Media Link Hostname Issue:

Media Link Settings (Link Provider): By default, Sitecore may be set up to resolve media links using a public-facing hostname, especially if the media items are served from a CDN or a specific media delivery server. This can cause the discrepancy you're seeing.

Sitecore Configuration (MediaLinkServerUrl): In Sitecore.config, you might have a Media.MediaLinkServerUrl setting that defines the hostname for media links. If this is set to the public site domain, all media links will use that domain, regardless of the context site.


How to Resolve This:
1. Check Media.MediaLinkServerUrl Setting:

Inspect your Sitecore.config or a specific configuration patch for the Media.MediaLinkServerUrl setting.

If it's set to https://public.site.com/, Sitecore will generate media links with this domain. If you want media links to use the same hostname as the microsite (micro.site.com), you'll need to configure the appropriate media link provider or use a different setting per site.

Try leaving the MediaLinkServerUrl setting empty so that media items resolve according to the current context site.


2. Contextual Media URLs:

You can customize the media link provider so that media links resolve
based on the context site. This ensures media links follow the same
hostname as the microsite.
var mediaUrlOptions = new MediaUrlOptions
 {
     AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = false,
     LowercaseUrls = true,
 };
 var mediaLink = MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem, mediaUrlOptions);



This code will generate media links without forcing a specific hostname, respecting the context site’s domain.
Hope this helps! Let me know in case you have any queries.

The media link server URL in the Rich Text Editor (RTE) is resolved from below key places:

Site Level Configuration:
Each site can have a specific media URL defined using the mediaLinkServerUrl attribute in the <site> node.

Global Setting:
If the media link is not set at the site level, Sitecore falls back to the global Media.MediaLinkServerUrl setting:


To find out where the media item links are generated from, you should check these configurations in your solution.
The media item will only contain a server URL if either Media.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl is set to true or the alwaysIncludeServerUrl setting in the link provider is also true.
In the code for generating media URLs, priority is given to the mediaLinkServerUrl settings over the site URL when constructing the final link.

Media link server url on the rich text are resolved from following two places.

At the site level, there is a attribute to configure media url using mediaLinkServerUrl attribute.

<site name="" mediaLinkServerUrl=""/>

This setting is introduced in Sitecore version 10.4.

If the media link is not set on the site node above, second place it sets the media url on the rich text is from the Media.MediaLinkServerUrl setting as below.

<setting name="Media.MediaLinkServerUrl" value=""/>

You can check for these settings on the solution in order to determine the place from where the media item links are getting generated.
The media item contains the server url only if the Media.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl setting is set to true or the alwaysIncludeServerUrl setting in the link provider is set to true.
Note: In case MediaLinkServerUrl setting is empty, it takes the url of the current site to compute the media url.
In the codebeside for the media url builder, when media link urls are generated, priority is given to the media link server url settings over the site url.

Update:
In order to have different server url according to the site, you will need to patch media provider in order to generate site specific media server url. You can find more details for the same here.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any queries.

We tried to add this setting but this setting making same URL to be available across the public and other microsites, and we want site specific URL only.

@PrashantTomar Currently till Sitecore 10.3, the setting for MediaLinkServerUrl setting is same for all the sites. Hence you are getting this issue. I have updated the answer above in which I implemented the same using custom media provider. Let me know in case you have any queries.

In Sitecore 10.4, now there is a setting at site level(as mentioned above) for media server link url, in order to generate it according to different sites.
